# form submit to save .html page into a folder

Tags: php, html, forms, action, autosave

here is where I'm at currently:

HTML:

```
<FORM NAME="submit-form" ACTION="results.php" METHOD="GET"> 

<INPUT TYPE="text" id="name" NAME="name" >
<INPUT TYPE="text" id="price" NAME="price" >
<INPUT TYPE="text" id="description" NAME="description" >
<INPUT TYPE="text" id="img" NAME="img" >

<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="See Demo" onclick="return validateForm()"> 
</form>
```

Long story short, this form I am using as a means to display the entered form data into a .php page where the input values are being injected into an existing html content via the `<?php echo $_GET[''] ?>` method.

Here is example results.php looks like:

```
/* other content */

   <div class="box">
      <h1><?php echo $_GET['name'] ?></h1>
      <p><?php echo $_GET['description'] ?></p>
      <div id="discounts"><h2><?php echo $_GET['discounts'] ?></h2></div>
      <img src="sitename/image/<?php echo $_GET['img'] ?>" />
   </div>

/* other content */
```

FInally, the end result after echoing values in results.php:

```
/* other content */

   <div class="box">
      <h1>JOE SMITH</h1>
      <p>BEST GUY WITH THE BEST STUFF!</p>
      <div id="discounts"><h2>30% OFF</h2></div>
      <img src="sitename/image/1.jpg" />
   </div>

/* other content */
```

So basically the content is being displayed in the final end result on the .php page. What I am hoping to achieve is to essentially save the contents of an entire div (e.g., .box ) from the results.php page as raw html to be saved as a .html page.

The purpose is to let customers fill out the form, see the end results, go back and fix anything if they made a mistake, once done then have them submit it to me as a .html file (preferably with the click of a button), later I can verify it is good and then put it on my website.

the box div is the only content I want to save to a .html file into my sites root folder, let's say /sitename/save-it-here/whatever.html

Ideally I would like the saved file name to begin with the text in the `<h2>` tag followed by the text in the `<h1>` tag, this would be sufficient for my purposes to give it a unique name.

I don't know where to begin to get this done as I searched around and all I saw was stuff related to databases but I am not using a database, I am using raw html to be inserted manually.

Any and all thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: `How to save contents of a div to a .html file using a button` *huh?!* Sorry but It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I'm sorry, if I knew how to phrase exactly what I need I may have had better results in my research efforts. But I think I did a good job of explaining it in the body. What do you need clarification on?

Comment: sorry but that's just a terrible idea. If you are trying to have dynamic content or user submitted content, I suggest using a database such as MySQL to post all submissions.

Comment: my klnowledge of databases are very limited at the moment, I was hoping to find a temporary solution using maybe a quick fix javascript.

Comment: @user3204638 spends some time and get a robust solution... MySQL is extremely easy to learn.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some links for tutorials on mysql databases or other useful info on databases. Thanks

Comment: Read the documentation for the database connection functions on php.net and look at the billions of questions about MySQL on this site.

Comment: I will, but in the meantime can anyone offer a jquery or javascript solution?

Answer (score 0):

Is this something appropriate to use for what I need?

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","me","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (Name, Price, Img)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[price]','$_POST[img]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }
 echo "1 record added";

 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```